# Validity of this geometry proof

Tags: geometry, linear-transformations

> In triangle ABC, D is the midpoint of AB and
>   E is the point
>   of trisection of BC nearer to
>   C. Given that  $\angle$ADC
>   = $\angle$ BAE
>   find  $\angle$BAC.
>   [Source Q5](http://www.bmoc.maths.org/home/bmolot.pdf#page=11)

Lets call the intersection of $DC$ and $AE$ Point $M$
We can construct the situation as follows.

Pick any line segment $AD$. Here we pick one free variable $x$ - the segments length.
 Pick a point $B$ on line $AD$ such that $AD$=$DB$. Pick a point $M$ such that $\angle$ ADM = $\angle$ DAM = $\alpha$. 
 Ignoring possible reflections here we have another free variable $\alpha$ 
Select Point $C$ such that it lies on the extension of $DM$ and $CB$ is trisected by the extension of $AM$

[image]

This situation is equivalent to the one described in the question however we now know the number of free variables that go into specifying a situation 2

If we pick $x=1$ and $\alpha=60 deg$ we can fairly easily show that $\angle$ BAC is a right angle.

It is here we notice that transforming the situation via matrices scaling in the directions of $AB$ and $AC$ does not change any of the questions constraints and preserves the right angle. The two transformations also require two degrees of freedom to reach any position and hence we prove that $\angle$ BAC is a right angle for all cases relevant to the question.

I know that this isn't very formal, however is there anyway to save this argument or is there a fatal flaw?

Also in this case it is very easy to see how the matrix transformations change the free variables. Scaling along $AC$ has the same effect as changing $\alpha$ and scaling along both axis has an equivalent effect to changing $x$. How would this play out in problems where the relationships aren't so clearly known?

Comment: Pretty nice proof I'd say. The last paragraph helps clear things a lot.

Comment: Would it be valid in a problem were we unable to determine the precise mapping between the free variables and the transformations? I feel like I'm missing an element proving that any ($x$,$\alpha$) tuple can be reached by the transformations

Comment: That can be obtained by looking at the continuity of each factor $x$ and $\alpha$.